# Vagrant fails to authenticate with GCP service account in provision

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, vagrant, gcloud

I tried to fetch some files from GCS in provision, but it didn't work as expected.

I created a service account and allowed it to access the target resources.
Everything works correctly when the script below is executed interactively. However, I got the following warning and errors when executed in provision.

1. **Could not open the configuration file: [/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default].**
   I assumed it was because .config directory didn't exist in root environment.
   I made .config directory as a test, but it didn't solve the issue.
2. **You do not currently have an active account selected.**
   I don't want to authenticate as user account, so I don't think I have to implement "gcloud auth login".

Stacktrace and script are as follows.

```
default: WARNING: Could not open the configuration file: [/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default].
    default: ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.keys.create) You do not currently have an active account selected.
    default: Please run:
    default: 
    default:   $ gcloud auth login
    default: 
    default: to obtain new credentials.
    default: 
    default: If you have already logged in with a different account:
    default: 
    default:     $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT
    default: 
    default: to select an already authenticated account to use.
    default: ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Could not read json file /root/key.json: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    default: ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
    default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 45: : command not found
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

```
# Install Google Cloud SDK
## Add URI to package source list
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

## Install packages needed
sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg

## Import Google Cloud public key
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

## Update and Install Google Cloud SDK
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y google-cloud-sdk

## Create service account key
cd ~ && gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json --iam-account=example@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com

## Activate service account
gcloud auth activate-service-account \
         example@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
         --key-file ~/key.json \
         --project example-project
```

- Host OS: MacOS 11.5.1
- Guest OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS(ubuntu/bionic64)
- Vagrant 2.2.17
- Virtualbox 6.1.26

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Okay. I’ll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, the error isn't the result of `gcloud auth activate-service-account` but from `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create`.

When you attempt `gcloud iam service-accounts keys create`, you've not authenticated `gcloud`, so you're not permitted to create a key.

You should create the key outside of the flow and (securely) transfer the key to the Vagrant process so that it may `gcloud auth activate-service-account`

Comment: I think you’re right. But I have no idea why creating keys doesn’t work in the first place.

Comment: Because you're not authenticated and so it's not permitted. Before any `gcloud` commands will succeed, you need to either `gcloud auth login` as a user account or `gcloud auth activate-service-account`. But, usually, to create a key, you'd login as a user account somewhere else, grab the key and then copy it to the machine where you want to `gcloud auth activate-service-account`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know I needed to be authenticated as a user account even if I created a json key file to login with service account. I don't think it's realistic to create it non-interactively in provision then

Comment: No, you don't. But you have 2 `gcloud` commands in the script in your question. You attempt to create the service account before *before* you're authenticated and that's not possible. If you already have the key (created elsewhere as I propose) then you can skip the first `gckoud` command that fails to create the key in your script and just use the second that authenticates with the key that you must have already created.

Comment: I changed the workflow as you proposed, and everything worked perfectly. Thank you for your advice